# WPF ListView with textbox in column header, tab problem

Tags: wpf, listview

I got a ListView in WPF with a GridView as view. I wanted to add textboxes to the column headings as filter mechanism. But when I set the cursor to the first column heading it does not tab to the next column heading textbox. Instead it goes to the next control after the ListView.

Here is the sample:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock>ABC</TextBlock>
                        <TextBox>YXZ</TextBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock>Spalte Nummer 2</TextBlock>
                        <TextBox></TextBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>                    
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

How will I make the cursor to tab from the first column header textbox to the second column header textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try setting [TabIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.tabindex.aspx) properties on your TextBox'es.

```
<TextBox TabIndex="0">YXZ</TextBox>

<TextBox TabIndex="1">Spalte Nummer 2</TextBox>
```

---

Edit: You should also set `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"` on your `ListView`.

Comment: This does not work. When pressing tab it leaves to the parent container (if you say so) and goes to the next element there which means going from listview to next control (a border in my test case).

Comment: With `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation` it works! I wonder why this is not the default.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the TabIndex attribute on each TextBox?

Comment: This does not work. When pressing tab it leaves to the parent container (if you say so) and goes to the next element there which means going from listview to next control (a border in my test case).